# iOS is there Rewarded interstitial Ad's Samples in swift language

Tags: ios, swift, admob

Before, I used AdMob's banner ad and open app ad in an iOS app. Now, I want to show its Rewarded interstitial ads. I checked the ([relevant web page of AdMob](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rewarded-interstitial#load_an_ad)), but the examples on this page are all in Objective C language. I am not familiar with Objective C language. Can anyone provide guidance in Swift language? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please take a look at below code

Comment: yes @AmodGokhale i have checked its simple Rewarded ad i am talking about new Rewarded interstitial ad's that ad mob release best for IOS you can check the info about that in the [link](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rewarded-interstitial#load_an_ad)

Comment: Got it. Updated answer with demo code (add 2 buttons and for each button loaded different type of advertisement)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds
class ViewController: UIViewController, GADFullScreenContentDelegate  {
    @IBOutlet weak var btnRwdClick: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnInters: UIButton!
    //var rewadAd: GADRewardedAd?
    var rewardInterstitialAd: GADRewardedInterstitialAd?
    var interstitial: GADInterstitialAd?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        GADRewardedInterstitialAd.load(
            withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6978759866", request: GADRequest()
        ) { (ad, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Rewarded ad failed to load with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            print("Loading Succeeded")
            self.rewardInterstitialAd = ad
            self.rewardInterstitialAd?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
        }
        let request = GADRequest()
        GADInterstitialAd.load(withAdUnitID:"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910",
                                        request: request,
                              completionHandler: { [self] ad, error in
                                if let error = error {
                                  print("Failed to load interstitial ad with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                  return
                                }
                                interstitial = ad
                                interstitial?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
                                                      
                              }
            )
    }
    
    @IBAction func rewadAdTouched(_ sender: Any) {
        if let ad = rewardInterstitialAd {
            
            ad.present(fromRootViewController: self,
                           userDidEarnRewardHandler: {
                             let reward = ad.adReward
                             // TODO: Reward the user.
                            print("Reward received with currency \(reward.amount), amount \(reward.amount.doubleValue)")
                           }
                  )
        } else {
            //Failed
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func interAdTouched(_ sender: Any) {
        if interstitial != nil {
            interstitial!.present(fromRootViewController: self)
          } else {
            print("Ad wasn't ready")
          }
    }
    func adDidPresentFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        print("Rewarded ad presented.")
    }
    
    func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {

            print("Ad dismiss full screen ad")

                if type(of: ad) == GADInterstitialAd.self {

                  print("InterstitialAd")

                   

                }else if  type(of: ad) == GADRewardedAd.self {

                  print("RewardedAd")

                }else if  type(of: ad) == GADRewardedInterstitialAd.self {
                    
                    print("Rewarded InterstitialAd")

                  }

        }
    
    func ad(
        _ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd,
        didFailToPresentFullScreenContentWithError error: Error
    ) {
        print("Rewarded ad failed to present with error: \(error.localizedDescription).")
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a swift example taken from [official AdMob documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial?hl=sr&skip_cache=false)

this is Dedicated test ad unit ID for iOS interstitials:
`ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910`

**Load an ad**

```swift
import GoogleMobileAds
import UIKit

class ViewController {

  private var interstitial: GADInterstitialAd?

  func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let request = GADRequest()
    GADInterstitialAd.load(withAdUnitID:"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910",
                                request: request,
                      completionHandler: { [self] ad, error in
                        if let error = error {
                          print("Failed to load interstitial ad with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                          return
                        }
                        interstitial = ad
                      }
    )
  }
}
```

**Register for callbacks**

```swift
class ViewController: GADFullScreenContentDelegate {

  private var interstitial: GADInterstitialAd?

  func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let request = GADRequest()
    GADInterstitialAd.load(withAdUnitID:"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910",
                                request: request,
                      completionHandler: { [self] ad, error in
                        if let error = error {
                          print("Failed to load interstitial ad with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                          return
                        }
                        interstitial = ad
                        interstitial?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
                      }
    )
  }

  /// Tells the delegate that the ad failed to present full screen content.
  func ad(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd, didFailToPresentFullScreenContentWithError error: Error) {
    print("Ad did fail to present full screen content.")
  }

  /// Tells the delegate that the ad presented full screen content.
  func adDidPresentFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
    print("Ad did present full screen content.")
  }

  /// Tells the delegate that the ad dismissed full screen content.
  func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
    print("Ad did dismiss full screen content.")
  }
}
```

**Display the ad**

```swift
@IBAction func doSomething(_ sender: Any) {
  if interstitial != nil {
    interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
  } else {
    print("Ad wasn't ready")
  }
}
```

Comment: This one is interstitials Ad's i am talking about Rewarded interstitial ad's [link](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rewarded-interstitial#load_an_ad)

Comment: GADRewardedInterstitialAd in ios not GADInterstitialAd you can read about it on the link